# why my first app doesn't show up on my phone?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating my first hello word apps, the first one shows just a hello word test and it worked on my phone, but i put a picture in the second one and run it the phone shows: the app has stopped ; my app looks on the xml design exactly how i wanted it !! (my phone has android 7 and i made the app with android 4)

the picture that i tried to show has a 3096x4128 resolution, but when i tried other picture that has less resolution has worked , i don't know if it's just a coincidence !i tried to change the app's android but same problem!

```
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/hugo" />

<TextView 
android:text="What a Picture!" 
android:textSize="36sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:padding="20dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
android:text="By AYMEN " 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="20dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:textSize="36sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to used image size is less than 2MB. This is the main reason to stop the app. So try to resize it & then used it in ImageView

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting OutOfMemory Error. To avoid this you can use the Picasso or Glide libraries

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

In Picasso you can use the .fit() method to optimize the image and load it into your ImageView without losing the image quality.

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
    .fit()
    // call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
    .into(imageViewFit);
```